# How to print a line along with its matching pattern using grep

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to print the matched string along with the matched line using grep or awk or sed, preferable grep as I want to do it on a huge file and grep gives me the best times.

For eg:
If I want to match 'hello'
then using the command: `grep 'hello' filename` , I get the result : `echo hello World`

Using the command: `grep -o 'hello' filename`, I can get the result :

```
hello
```

Anyway I can get the result :

```
echo hello World , hello
```

or similar to this.
Help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

hello is just an example, it can be a variable too taken from a file, hence it is not static, if we have multiple matching then all of them should be appended.

**EDIT 2**

As an example to the earlier edit, consider a file *keywords* which has contents

```
hello
why
```

and we have another file on which we would be checking these keywords *testfile* which has contents

```
this line contains hello world
this line contains why hello world
```

so when we run grep, we can get the answer like :

**Description|regex(tagged for grep result),**

```
this line contains hello world|hello
this line contains why hello world|hello,why
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the expected output?

Comment: grep does line based matching, one line can match the pattern multiple times, what would you print in this case? You want to append the **regex pattern** (`hello` is regex too) or the **matched part in the line** to the output?

Comment: hello is just an example, it can be a variable too taken from a file, hence it is not static, if we have multiple matching then all of them can be appended, matched part or just regex I think can be simply solved using -F

Comment: @AklankJain could you please show us some expected output?

Comment: @xtonousou i have added an example in the description

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=' , ' 'match($0,/PATTERN/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),$0}' file
```

See awk manual [`match()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-match-regexp-in-string)

Comment: Right. `awk -v OFS=' , ' 'match($0,/PATTERN/){print $0, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file` to produce the expected output.

Comment: I see. May I ask why you never use `awk '...' OFS='something' file`? I mean it's POSIX and requires a few less keystrokes.

Comment: Because variables defined after the script aren't available in the BEGIN section (try `awk 'BEGIN{print OFS}' OFS=,` vs `awk -v OFS=, 'BEGIN{print OFS}'`) and I'd rather not have to think about where my variables are available in which contexts. I also am generally against defining variables sequentially **after** they are used - I want to see my variables initial values before the variables show up in my script, not after! Finally - it clutters up ARGV so I can no longer just loop through ARGV to see my input file names.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. If you ever want to get me gnashing my teeth write `awk -F, 'script' OFS=,`. That has all of the above issues AND having to hard-code the same value twice (`,` in this case) and having the 2 variables that MUST have the same values being initialized as far apart as possible so on a revision it's easy to forget/break one. Grrr....

Comment: Yeah, you mentioned the issue with defining the same value twice once. I was just curious why you also not use it in this case where just one value has to be set. I guess it is most useful in the rare case where you want to do something like this `awk '...' FS=, file1 FS=; file2`. Right?

Comment: Right, setting variables to different values between files is exactly what the capability is useful for.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***sed*** approach:

Let's say we have file `testfile` with contents:

```
dfdsgg
echo hello World
dfget2rfd hel
sdfs hello .. hello again
ssdf h3tgdfg
```

---

```
sed -n 's/.*\(hello\).*/&, \1/p' testfile
```

The output:

```
echo hello World, hello
sdfs hello .. hello again, hello
```